# Why doesn't Eigen converge for tiny constant matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am running repeated matrix diagonalization routines for small complex valued square matrices (dimension < 10), but encountered a failure on a small constant value matrix. The ComplexEigenSolver doesn't converge, returning empty objects for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I have checked this problem by trying to solve the matrix with values all 1, but this works fine. My problem must be related to the small values of my matrix.

```cpp
MatrixXcd matrix(2,2);
matrix(0,0) = std::complex<double>(1.4822e-322, 0);
matrix(0,1) = std::complex<double>(1.4822e-322, 0);
matrix(1,0) = std::complex<double>(1.4822e-322, 0);
matrix(1,1) = std::complex<double>(1.4822e-322, 0);
ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcd> ces;
ces.compute(matrix);
ces.eigenvalues();
ces.eigenvectors();
ces.info();
```

This gives empty eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and returns 2 from ces.info().
I expect it to simply give eigenvalues with entries 0 and 2.96e-322 (a scaled version of the matrix of ones given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones)

Are the values too small?

Comment: Yes. Such small double values make calculations unstable. You are very close to what double can represent, so changes are high that limit is reached during computation and the results are off.

Comment: if you dont know what it is, read about the condition number, it tells you how close the matrix is to something that is hard (or impossible) to solve for, I would expect a rather high conidition number for this matrix

Comment: Note that your numbers are [denormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) from the beginning. Further calculations on them will very likely underflow, possibly to zero.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It will make no impact if I set matrices like this to zero, so I will just do that. I'll look down this condition number/denormal path to identify a value at which I should start doing this.